# mass find deleted image rows from a table in sql

Tags: sql

in my sql files, there is a table call "user", there is a "Photolink" field within this table, they should store data like: abc.com/acc.jpg

now the problem is some of the images already deleted, some of links like abc.com /acc.jpg may not showing images again..

i can try to find one by one, but it use too much time.

now I would like to find which row with deleted images?? is it possible to find them mass? thanks

Comment: There is no other way than to go through all the URLs, try to retrieve the image and if that fails, remove the value from the column. If you want to do that inside the database, you will need some procedural code and network functions. These are completely vendor specific, so you have to tell us which DBMS product you are using ("SQL" is the name of a query language used by all relational databases, it's not the name of a database product).

Answer (score 0):

Write a test in java or js, turn this url to BASE64Encoder.

All the operation needed to confirm your network is ping, otherwise you will drop good img url.

When using java, if catch exception then replace url to empty string in db.

Comment: maybe my words express not good.as far as my concerned,Through  all records by java code,not try it one by one.